# How to find extra packages in package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, npm

I can see jquery in my package-lock.json file but not in package.json which actually means that some of my 3rd party libraries are using jquery internally so wanted to figure it out.

package-lock.json

```
"requires": {
        "@jest/reporters": "^25.2.6",
        "@jest/test-result": "^25.2.6",
        "@jest/types": "^25.2.6",
        "@types/jest": "^25.0.0",
        "ansi-parser": "^3.2.9",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "chalk": "^4.0.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
        "diff2html": "^3.0.0",
        "holderjs": "^2.9.6",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "moment": "^2.23.0",
        "mustache": "^4.0.0",
        "pkg-up": "^3.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "yargs": "^15.0.0"
      },
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.7",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.5",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.159",
    "@types/react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "easy-peasy": "^3.2.6",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.6.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "fuse.js": "^3.6.1",
    "gojs": "^2.1.11",
    "gojs-react": "^1.0.5",
    "i18next": "^19.3.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.0.2",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-ace": "^8.1.0",
    "react-animate-height": "^2.0.20",
    "react-color": "^2.18.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-draggable": "^4.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.3.4",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "sanitize.css": "^11.0.0",
    "sass-rem": "^2.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.4",
    "uniqid": "^5.2.0",
    "validator": "^13.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: That doesnt look like a full package-lock.json to me (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json)... Have you run `npm i`?

Comment: if you're using yarn you can run `yarn why jquery` and it will tell you which package(s) require jquery and which version(s) are installed. NPM might have a similar command.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean when you say _"so wanted to figure it out"_ - figure out what exactly? If you are wanting to find out which packages use _jquery_ as a dependency then: **1)** `cd` to your project directory. **2)** Then utilize the [npm ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ls) command, i.e. run the following command: `npm ls jquery`

Comment: yes I want to check which package is using jquery as it's peer dependencies

Comment: you can use `npm explain jquery` to see which packages using it as peer dependency